# How to build (configure options) latest apache on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, apache-2.2

I cannot figure out what are the correct `./configure` options to build apache on an (oldish) ubuntu distribution that would preserve the same configuration file system.

I need apache with MPM Worker and mod_WSGI

I've found this [No apache MPM package installed error](https://serverfault.com/questions/107888/no-apache-mpm-package-installed-error) related question but there's no answer solving my issue. httpd -l says "prefork.c" which sounds like my desired 'mpm-worker' has not been compiled.

So far:

```
# get latest tar from a mirror
wget http://apache.crihan.fr/dist//httpd/httpd-2.2.19.tar.gz
# untar
tar -xf httpd-2.2.19.tar.gz
# get inside
cd httpd-2.2.19
```

the current [configure](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/programs/configure.html):

```
 ./configure --enable-shared-mods=all --prefix=/usr/lib/apache2 --with-mpm=worker
```

(it actually say in the doc that 'all' does not build the modules, so I guess I'll have to fix that later)

and of course:

```
 make
 sudo make install
```

But then:

```
 No apache MPM package installed
```

and indeed no MPM exists under `/usr/lib/apache2/mpm-worker/apache2`

How do I compile/build MPM-worker? Is there any other configuration parameter I am missing?
Should I create a `ln -s PATH /usr/sbin/apache2` to be compliant with ubuntu /etc/init.d/apache2 , or is there another suggested way?

Comment: Specifically which version of Ubuntu?

Comment: @jrwren : Karmic 9.10 - the included apache2 is 2.2.12

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I hunted down this url which is the rules file for the deb from dapper (before you replied to my comment.)

http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-branches/ubuntu/dapper/apache2/dapper/view/head:/debian/rules

Here is the home for apache2 in ubuntu.

https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/apache2

I couldn't find a link to Karmic from there, but i just replaced the name in the url.

https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/karmic/+source/apache2

Browse a version and click the code tab and see the rules file in the code repository for the karmic release.

http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-branches/ubuntu/karmic/apache2/karmic/view/head:/debian/rules  SAYS:

```
 --enable-layout=Debian --enable-so \
                  --with-program-name=apache2  \
          --with-ldap=yes --with-ldap-include=/usr/include \
          --with-ldap-lib=/usr/lib \
          --with-suexec-caller=www-data \
          --with-suexec-bin=/usr/lib/apache2/suexec \
          --with-suexec-docroot=/var/www \
          --with-suexec-userdir=public_html \
          --with-suexec-logfile=/var/log/apache2/suexec.log \
          --with-suexec-uidmin=100 \
          --enable-suexec=shared \
          --enable-log-config=static --enable-logio=static \
          --with-apr=/usr/bin/apr-1-config \
          --with-apr-util=/usr/bin/apu-1-config \
          --with-pcre=yes \
          --enable-pie
```

AND

```
AP2_MODS_CONFARGS =   --enable-authn-alias=shared --enable-authnz-ldap=shared  \
          --enable-disk-cache=shared --enable-cache=shared \
          --enable-mem-cache=shared --enable-file-cache=shared \
          --enable-cern-meta=shared --enable-dumpio=shared --enable-ext-filter=shared \
          --enable-charset-lite=shared --enable-cgi=shared \
          --enable-dav-lock=shared --enable-log-forensic=shared \
          --enable-ldap=shared --enable-proxy=shared \
          --enable-proxy-connect=shared --enable-proxy-ftp=shared \
          --enable-proxy-http=shared --enable-proxy-ajp=shared \
          --enable-proxy-balancer=shared --enable-ssl=shared \
          --enable-authn-dbm=shared --enable-authn-anon=shared \
          --enable-authn-dbd=shared --enable-authn-file=shared \
          --enable-authn-default=shared --enable-authz-host=shared \
          --enable-authz-groupfile=shared --enable-authz-user=shared \
          --enable-authz-dbm=shared --enable-authz-owner=shared \
          --enable-authnz-ldap=shared --enable-authz-default=shared \
          --enable-auth-basic=shared --enable-auth-digest=shared \
          --enable-dbd=shared --enable-deflate=shared \
          --enable-include=shared --enable-filter=shared \
          --enable-env=shared --enable-mime-magic=shared \
          --enable-expires=shared --enable-headers=shared \
          --enable-ident=shared --enable-usertrack=shared \
          --enable-unique-id=shared --enable-setenvif=shared \
          --enable-version=shared --enable-status=shared \
          --enable-autoindex=shared --enable-asis=shared \
          --enable-info=shared --enable-cgid=shared \
          --enable-dav=shared --enable-dav-fs=shared \
          --enable-vhost-alias=shared --enable-negotiation=shared \
          --enable-dir=shared --enable-imagemap=shared \
          --enable-actions=shared --enable-speling=shared \
          --enable-userdir=shared --enable-alias=shared \
          --enable-rewrite=shared --enable-mime=shared \
          --enable-substitute=shared
```

That will let you build apache with the same options as the installed deb.

Although, I think an easier approach would be to use a backports build, or make one yourself. Get the source deb and build it under Karmic.

Comment: Even though I did not manage to get the right build simply using the  ./configuration params you pasted, your links really shed some light on how to do it, so your final suggestion of getting the deb source and building them really is the way to go!